# ¿Cómo posicionar un botón en pantalla móvil?

Tags: css, responsive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando bootstrap, pero no logro posicionar esos botones conforme a las fotografías de fondo, lo intente con position, con display, y ninguno resulta, les dejo mi código:

```
<div class="container-fluid hero-text-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 parents">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/padres'">SOY MAMÁ/SOY PAPÁ</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 player">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/jugadores'">SOY JUGADOR/JUGADORA</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary coach" onclick="window.location.href='/entrenadores'">SOY ENTRENADOR/ENTRENADORA</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div

.hero-text-2 button {
    outline: 0;
    padding: 8px 28px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1b4688;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-size: 18pt;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: '#####';
    border-radius: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma es agregar las clases "d-flex" y "justify-content-center" a los contenedores de los button:

```
<div class="container-fluid hero-text-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 parents d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/padres'">SOY MAMÁ/SOY PAPÁ</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 player d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/jugadores'">SOY JUGADOR/JUGADORA</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary coach" onclick="window.location.href='/entrenadores'">SOY ENTRENADOR/ENTRENADORA</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: si me acomodó los botones al centro pero el espacio aun es corto space-evenly no funciona :(

Comment: Para dar espacio vertical primero hay que darle una altura mayor al contenedor, o agregarle margin-top, hay varias formas, también se puede agregar margen vertical a los botones